# Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.0 error by pytesser

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

i am trying to convert a text image into text. I am using `pytesser` in python for that I have already installed tesseract but on running even the following code:

```
from pytesser import *
im = Image.open('phototest.tif')
text = image_to_string(im)
print text
```

I get the following error:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.
```

and nothing gets printed nothing (no result).
Any help on the above problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting your image to another format and see if you have the same issue. I had this same problem using Tesseract form the command line. I had a `bmp` file, I saved the files in my pre processing to `png` and tesseract worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1), which will automatically convert your image and process it correctly.